# Convert from object to AWS Kinesis -> Java Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Date` out of VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT token

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jackson, amazon-kinesis

I am working on a AWS lambda function in order to get dynamically a SNS Event or a Kinesis Event, to do so, in my lambda function I am getting an Object as parameter:

```
@Override
public GatewayResponse handleRequest(final Object object, Context context)
```

Then, I am using Jackson in order to convert it to SNS or Kinesis dynamically:

```
public static SNSEvent convertObjectToSNSEvent(Object object) {
    return objectMapper.convertValue(object, SNSEvent.class);
}

public static KinesisEvent convertToKinesisEvent(Object object) {
    return objectMapper.convertValue(object, KinesisEvent.class);
}
```

The problem is that, when I'm using the `convertToKinesisEvent` function I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Date` out of VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT token
```

SNSEvent convertion works fine, but Kinesis does not, I have realized that is because in the Kinesis Json, the time stamp (***approximateArrivalTimestamp*** field) is represented with decimals:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "kinesis": {
        "partitionKey": "partitionKey-03",
        "kinesisSchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "data": "eyJpZCI6MjY2MjU4NSwiZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiJUZXN0IFBheWxvYWQifQ==",
        "sequenceNumber": "49545115243490985018280067714973144582180062593244200961",
        "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1.57538737506E9
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:kinesis",
      "eventID": "shardId-000000000000:49545115243490985018280067714973144582180062593244200961",
      "invokeIdentityArn": "arn:aws:iam::EXAMPLE",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "eventName": "aws:kinesis:record",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:EXAMPLE",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I execute the same code with a integer in the timestamp it works fine:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "kinesis": {
        "partitionKey": "partitionKey-03",
        "kinesisSchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "data": "eyJpZCI6MjY2MjU4NSwiZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiJUZXN0IFBheWxvYWQifQ==",
        "sequenceNumber": "49545115243490985018280067714973144582180062593244200961",
        "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 11234432432
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:kinesis",
      "eventID": "shardId-000000000000:49545115243490985018280067714973144582180062593244200961",
      "invokeIdentityArn": "arn:aws:iam::EXAMPLE",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "eventName": "aws:kinesis:record",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:EXAMPLE",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the full error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Date` out of VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT token
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.KinesisEvent["Records"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.KinesisEvent$KinesisEventRecord["kinesis"]->com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.KinesisEvent$Record["approximateArrivalTimestamp"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3922)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:3853)
    at util.JsonUtil.convertToKinesisEvent(JsonUtil.java:28)
    at pojos.RecordsHandler.getMessages(RecordsHandler.java:38)
    at handler.App.handleRequest(App.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:261)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:178)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:906)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:341)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:63)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:114)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.Date` out of VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT token
```

Does someone know what is happening?

--Update--
Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.685</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this project use Maven/Gradle? If so, could you edit your question with the list of dependencies that you're using along with their versions?

Comment: @JacobG. updated, thanks

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to verify that your libraries were up to date. I'll see if I can find a solution for this.

Comment: It looks like this is an open issue in the `aws-lambda-java-core` GitHub repository: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/issues/81

Comment: Just curious, how is that JSON in your question being serialized? i.e. are you serializing a specific POJO to that JSON?

Comment: I'm serializing it into the AWS Kinesis class, http://javadox.com/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events/1.1.0/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/KinesisEvent.KinesisEventRecord.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so what I ended up doing was to add my custom deserializer to Jackson in order to solve the problem:

```
public class TimestampDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(jsonParser.getValueAsLong());
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
}
```

And then add a custom serializer

```
public class TimestampSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(date.toString());
    }
}
```

And then add it to Jackson and it worked, I don't know if there is another solution but It achieve my goal

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Date.class, new TimestampSerializer());
module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new TimestampDeserializer());
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that there is additional work that the Lambda service does in order to convert some requests into Java objects.

This is to handle request types which don't conform to normal Java naming standards.

You can find the code which does this work - [aws-lambda-java-serialization](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-serialization)